# How to send json to mvc controller?

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I need to send a JSON string to MVC Controller that returns a ModelAndView object but I dont know how to send the json without AJAX and, if I send the json with AJAX the ModelAndView not redirects me.

One of the solutions I have is send the json by URL parameter but I dont like see all the JSON in the browser.

This is my JS code:

```
                $('#btnDetalleActivo')
                        .on('click',function() {
                            var data = $('#tablaActivo').bootstrapTable('getSelections')[0].dto;

                                    if (!$.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                                        $(location)
                                                .attr({'href' : "/AT/DetalleActivo",
                                                        data : data});

                                    } else {
                                        swal.info("Debe seleccionar un activo")
                                    }
                                });
```

This is the code of the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "DetalleActivo" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public ModelAndView getDetalleActivo(@RequestParam Activo activo, HttpServletRequest request) {

ModelAndView modelAndView = null;
ParamProcedureConsultaBean paramProcedureConsulta = new ParamProcedureConsultaBean();

DetalleActivoWrapper wrapperDetalleActivo;

paramProcedureConsulta.setPivIFGD(activo.getIFGD());
paramProcedureConsulta.setPivTABLA("F01");
paramProcedureConsulta.setPivPERIODO(activo.getFECHAREPORTING());
paramProcedureConsulta.setPivIdMovimiento(activo.getIDMOVIMIENTO());
paramProcedureConsulta.setPivENTIDAD(activo.getENTIDADINM());
paramProcedureConsulta.setPivMACRO(activo.getMCRO());
paramProcedureConsulta.setPivDEPENDENCIA(activo.getDCIA());
paramProcedureConsulta.setPivCUENTA(activo.getNCTA());
paramProcedureConsulta.setPivIdPARTIC(activo.getNNIF());

DetalleActivoBean detalleActivoBean = detalleActivoService.getDetalleActivo(paramProcedureConsulta);

if (detalleActivoBean.getRespuesta().getCODRETORNO() == 0) {
    wrapperDetalleActivo = new DetalleActivoWrapper(detalleActivoBean.getResultado().getDetalleActivo());
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("ArbolApp/Activos/DetalleActivos", "detalleActivo", wrapperDetalleActivo);
} else {
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("ArbolApp/ArbolIndex", "mensajeError",
        detalleActivoBean.getRespuesta().getMSGERROR());
}

return modelAndView;
}
```

I hope you understand my english!

Comment: Use jquery.get link: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: First you need to send json and in code commented i see ajax request type as 'POST' while your controller is decorated with GET, try changing method = { RequestMethod.GET }) to POST and uncomment ajax call

Comment: I can't use Ajax to do the call because Spring MVC don't redirects me to the View, I tell it in the question. I need do the call by another way, like href for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, in your pom.xml add dependency:

```
<!-- Need this for json to/from object -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

then you can send any JSON object and they will be converted to Java objects automatically, just make sure that Java class variables have the same name as the fields of a JSON object like, if this is your JSON object.

```
{field1: "value1", field2: "value2"}
```

then you should make java class like,

```
public class Test{ String field1, field2;}
```

and receive them as,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someMethod", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView someMethod(@RequestBody Test test) {

    //your code
}
```

hope this would help.